# How to configure a transmit GUE tunnel using iproute2 for IPv6

Tags: linux, networking, iproute, tunneling

I am trying add a transmit GUE tunnel with GRE as the header using IPV6 addresses in linux like this:

```
ip -6 link add name gue1 type ip6gre remote $REMOTE_IPV6 local $LOCAL_IPV6 dev eth0 encap gue encap-dport 42424
```

Both $REMOTE_IPV6 and $LOCAL_IPV6 are valid IPV6 addresses. But I keep getting this error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

If I remove `encap gue` then it doesn't give that error since it then defaults to encap type of none. However, the helptext from `ip link help ip6gre` seems to imply that the valid encap types are `encap { fou | gue | none }`. What could be the issue causing the encap type to be invalid here?

Comment: encap none runs without error but encap fou or encap gue does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR:

Run this first:

```
modprobe fou6
```

---

### More details

Tested on Linux kernel 5.10.x

There are two issues, one possible issue with the configuration (which doesn't cause the error but might prevent correct operations later), the other that I can only consider a minor bug.

- the GUE receiving port appears to have to be declared first

  According to online blogs like [An intriduction to Linux virtual interfaces: Tunnels | Red Hat Developer](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/05/17/an-introduction-to-linux-virtual-interfaces-tunnels#gue):

  > ```
  > # ip fou add port 5555 gue
  > # ip link add name tun1 type ipip remote 192.168.1.1 local 192.168.1.2 ttl 225 encap gue encap-sport auto encap-dport 5555
  > ```
  >
  > This will set up a GUE receive port for IPIP bound to 5555, and an
  > IPIP tunnel configured for GUE encapsulation.

  So a receive port must be declared first with an `ip fou add port XXXX gue` command and it will be reused in the `encap-dport XXXX` part of the second command. The first command is described in [`ip fou(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/iproute2/ip-fou.8) in case more restrictions should be added.
- but `ip fou add port 42424 gue` doesn't work either

  ```
  # ip fou add port 42424 gue
  RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
  Error talking to the kernel
  ```

  It appears, and this looks like a bug to me, that the kernel module `fou` isn't autoloaded by using this command. GUE is just an additional mode to FOU handled by the same kernel module `fou`.

  ```
  # modprobe fou
  # ip fou add port 42424 gue
  # ip -6 link add name gue1 type ip6gre remote $REMOTE_IPV6 local $LOCAL_IPV6 dev eth0 encap gue encap-dport 42424
  RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
  ```

  Nor is the kernel module `fou6` loaded for the IPv6 part...

  Actually the `-6` option had to be added to the `ip fou` command or the port will be opened on an IPv4 socket.

  ```
  # modprobe fou6
  # ip -6 fou add port 42424 gue
  # ip -6 link add name gue1 type ip6gre remote $REMOTE_IPV6 local $LOCAL_IPV6 dev eth0 encap gue encap-dport 42424
  #
  ```

Comment: I added a note about `ip -6 fou`